# In JavaScript/jQuery, how to retrieve the url of an ajax call after the call is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a web program in JavaScript where I have to make multiple ajax calls, and I need to figure out how to get the url after making an ajax call to the url. The ajax calls are made in a for loop that loops through an array of urls. So the code for the ajax request and the function that processes the return of the request look something like this:

```
requester = function(url){
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://url of my proxy?url=" + escape(url),
        type : "GET",
        data-type : "xml"
    }).done(dataProcessor);
};

dataProcessor = function(data){
    //a bunch of code, including things where I must have the url for the ajax request
};
```

So, how can I get that url?

Comment: Why not `function requester(url) { ... }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply save it and pass it to your function:

```
requester = function(url){
    var fullURL = "http://url of my proxy?url=" + escape(url)
    $.ajax({
        url : fullURL,
        type : "GET",
        data-type : "xml"
    }).done(function(data) {dataProcessor(data, fullURL)});
};

dataProcessor = function(data, url){
    //a bunch of code, including things where I must have the url for the ajax request
};
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!! I wasn't sure how to pass a parameter when a function is called this way because I'm new to web programming, but this makes perfect sense now, and it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of closures

```
requester = function(url){
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://url of my proxy?url=" + escape(url),
        type : "GET",
        data-type : "xml"
    }).done(function(data) {

         alert(url);

    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

It's available from the `this` value, which is the [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR).

```
dataProcessor = function(data){
    console.log(this.url);
};
```

Comment: Down-vote on a correct and fast solution?